# How to associate two different inputs collected in different times, and recall back them when it is needed?

Tags: jquery, string, data-binding

I want to bind two different inputs in the form of integers, collected on a button click event, and want to call back them! But I am stuck, take a look at my code:

```
$(function (){
var j;
$("#first").on("click" , function (){
j++;
});
$("#second").on("click" , function (){
var d = new Date();
var dhou = d.getHours();
var dmin = d.getMinutes();
var dsec = d.getSeconds();
var dtotal = dhou+dmin+dsec;
});
$("#third").on("click" , function (){
//I want to recall here both dtotal and j variable together collected in different times, like in the form (dtotal , j) = (72000,1) , (72809,2) , (73578 ,3) and so on...
});
});
```

> Please read the comment inside the code present inside `#third ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variables outside both functions, in a scope they can both access. you have already done that for that j variable so it is available for you in the **third event** but you haven't declared variables which are in the **second event** outside, so you can not use them..your problem will be solved once you declares them outside of both functions..

```js
$(function (){
var j=0;
var d = "";
var dhou = "";
var dmin = "";
var dsec = "";
var dtotal = "";
$("#first").on("click" , function (){
j++;
});
$("#second").on("click" , function (){
d = new Date();
dhou = d.getHours();
dmin = d.getMinutes();
dsec = d.getSeconds();
dtotal = dhou+"-"+dmin+"-"+dsec;
});
$("#third").on("click" , function (){
$("#result").append("<br/>"+dtotal +","+ j);
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<button id="first">one</button>
<button id="second">two</button>
<button id="third">three</button>

</br>

<p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```